# How I can use the scanf function instead of including information in the code by objective c?

Tags: xcode, scanf

How I can use the `scanf` function instead of including information in the code by objective c?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person: NSObject

{
NSString *personname;
int personage;
int personweight;
int personheight;
}

-(void) setPersonName:(NSString *)name;
-(void) setPersonAge:(int)age;
-(void) setPersonWeight:(int)weight;
-(void) setPersonHeight:(int)Height;
-(void) SetprintPerson;

@end


@implementation Person

-(void) setPersonName:(NSString *)name
{
personname = name;
}
-(void) setPersonAge:(int)age
{
personage = age;
}
-(void) setPersonWeight:(int)weight 
{
personweight = weight;
}
-(void) setPersonHeight:(int)Height
{
personheight = Height;
}
-(void) SetprintPerson
{
NSLog(@"\n person name: %@ \n person age: %i \n person weight: %i KG \n person Height: %i         CM",personname,personage,personweight,personheight);
}


@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool
{
    // I wont to use the scanf here .
    Person *user = [[Person alloc]init];
    [user setPersonName:@"ahmed"];
    [user setPersonAge:30];
    [user setPersonWeight:176];
    [user setPersonHeight:90];
    [user SetprintPerson];


}
return 0;
}
```

I'm in the way of learning, and was having difficulty in the work as requested.

Answer (score 0):

scanf just lets you read an Array of chars
so you need something like this:

```
char str[100]; //a C char Array with 100 Chars  
scanf("%99s", str); //leave the last one empty becaue of '\0'
[user setPersonName:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:str]]; //initialize a new NSString
```

Integers are easy you can read them like this:

```
int age;
scanf("%d", &age);
[user setPersonAge: age];
```